# remote code execution in ruby with constantize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security

I'm trying to wrap my head around remote code execution vulnerabilities in ruby/rails when `contantize` is used.

I understand that being able to provide *any* class name to the server could be potentially dangerous, but I'm wondering if this *by itself* is dangerous.

for example, if a rails controller code looks something like this (i.e. executes a hardcoded method on the instantiated object):

```
klass = params[:class].classify.constantize
klass.do_something_with_id(params[:id]) if klass.respond_to?('do_something_with_id')
```

Is this code vulnerable? Or only in combination with being able to also specify the method to be called on the class?

Comment: I don't know if this is vulnerable, but class name in param looks not nice at all. Can you post your real purpose? It's highly possible there is a better solution without using these.

Comment: I totally agree that there's probably a better way and even if it's not vulnerable *now*, it would be better not to use something like this. However, I'm just curious about the theoretical exploit possibility (or lack of) at this stage, not on how to improve the code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turning a string into a constant isn't dangerous in itself, but how that constant is used is potentially dangerous (i.e. the method that is then called).

If you really need to do this, then it's probably best to provide a list of classes that are allowed. E.g.

```
klass = params[:class].classify
if %w(Class1 Class2 Class3).include? klass
  klass.constantize.do_something_with_id(params[:id])
else
  raise 'Forbidden'
end
```

However it's done, it helps you to sleep at night to know that the input is considerably limited.

#### Update

Another way of controlling the creation, which is more explicit but also more verbose, is to use a case statement:

```
def create_klass(option)
  case option
  when "option1"
    Class1
  when "option2"
    Class2
  when "option3"
    Class3
  else
    raise "Unknown option"
  end
end
```

This way, you don't need to expose the internals of your system to the client. If there are many options, then you could use a hash with options mapping to classes.

Comment: ok, that's good to know, and I definitely agree that whitelisting makes much more sense in those situations. Just wanted to clarify more specifically. Tools like Brakeman seem to warn you whenever you use `constantize` regardless of any whitelist or checks around it, so I wasn't sure if *by itself* this can be exploited, or only in combination.

Comment: Yes, only in combination. Brakeman is (probably rightly) being over protective. A way round it could be to have a kind of factory method, I'll add an example to the answer.

Comment: I think I'm quite clear on solutions, was trying to understand the *problem* more clearly. Thanks again for putting time to explaining this @joonty.